# Suppose there's sequence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}y_{n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true, that OR $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=0$, OR $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_{n}=0$?
I think there's also another special case, which is related to subsequences (except both of them are zero ofc)
And can both of them diverge to infinity, but the product still remain zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x_{2n}=y_{2n-1}=\sqrt{n}\qquad y_{2n}=x_{2n-1}=\frac1n\qquad (n\geqslant1)$$

Answer (score 2):

(1). $x_n = 0, n$ even and $x_n = 1, n$ odd and $y_n = 1, n$ even and $y_n = 0, n$ odd.

(2). $x_n = 0, n$ even and $x_n = n^2, n$ odd and $y_n = n^2, n$ even and $y_n = 0, n$ odd.

*EDIT:* As the above examples show that both $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ can have a subsequence which diverges to $\infty.$ But it can not happen that both $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ diverges to infinity but $(x_ny_n)$ converges to zero because the terms of $x_n$ and $y_n$ will be bigger and bigger and so is the product $x_ny_n.$ On the other hand, if you look at the given examples (specifically the example given by *Did*), you will notice that for any given $n,$ the terms $x_n$ and $y_n$ *cancelling out* each other to make to product $x_ny_n$ bounded.

Answer (score 2):

$x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ even and $1$ if $n$ is odd. $y_n=\frac{1}{n}$ when $n$ is odd and $1$ when $n$ is even.